# Would it be possible to create logical circuits out of insects?

Tags: entomology, behaviour, sociality

Could one organise ants, bees or any insects to do addition using logical gates:

- AND,
- OR,
- NOT,
- XOR.

As inputs/signals one could imagine for example that 1 would be food and 0 would be no food.

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/artl.2009.15.3.Michael.008

Comment: @Roland Can you please turn your link into an answer?

Comment: @jakebeal Link only answers are not allowed and I won't invest the time to summarize the study. Feel free to do so.

Comment: @Roland Done; it's not so hard to do a simple version.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a problem in biology. Is it akin to one on whether you can train elephants to dance?

Comment: @David You just answered your own question. Logical gates can built from a lot of things, not just electric circuits, I was curious how they translate into insect behaviour.

Comment: In which case I would suggest it is really not on-topic here, as the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) makes clear.

Comment: @David How about this: "is there an insect with a special natural behaviour that resembles a logical circuit?"

Comment: How about it? Sounds on-topic. But a bit strange. I would have thought certain aspects of insect behaviour might qualify, but not the insect itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, yes, it appears to be possible, and a number of people have performed investigations in this area. For example, see the ["Ant-Based Computing"](https://doi.org/10.1162/artl.2009.15.3.Michael.008) article suggested by @Roland, whose abstract explains the concept at a high level:

> A biologically and physically plausible model for ants and pheromones is proposed. It is argued that the mechanisms described in this model are sufficiently powerful to reproduce the necessary components of universal computation. The claim is supported by illustrating the feasibility of designing arbitrary logic circuits, showing that the interactions of ants and pheromones lead to the expected behavior, and presenting computer simulation results to verify the circuits' working. The conclusions of this study can be taken as evidence that coherent deterministic and centralized computation can emerge from the collective behavior of simple distributed Markovian processes such as those followed by biological ants, but also, more generally, by artificial agents with limited computational and communication abilities.

Whether such a computer is good for anything besides curiosity is another question, but curiosity and art are fine starting points for any investigation.

Comment: As an aside, this idea was explored by the sci-fi/fantasy author [Terry Pratchet](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Hex) in his 1996 book Soul Music, prefiguring the actual research here.